# Two Columns with same header text in gridview in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having a gridview in which I don't want to display Header Text for two columns and two columns should have same header name (INFA). Gridview Looks Like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView6" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DayOfWeek" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateOfMonth" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Emp_Name" HeaderText="INFA" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Group_Name" HeaderText="INFA" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Emp_Id" HeaderText="Mainframe" ItemStyle-Width="30" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I need to flip this gridview and make rows into columns and columns into rows. The logic was working fine when I had different names in Header Text for all DataFields. But in my requirement I don't need a Header text for two columns and two columns must have same header text (As shown above in Gridview). When I run my logic with no column name as shown above I get this error:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.DuplicateNameException: A column named '&nbsp;' already belongs to this DataTable.
```

My logic is:

```
protected void btnConvert_Data()
{
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("GridView_Data");

    foreach (TableCell cell in GridView6.HeaderRow.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Text == "")
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("");
        }
        else
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
        }
    }

    dt.Rows.Add("IST Hours");
    //dt.Rows.Add("8:45AM-6PM");
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView6.Rows)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = row.Cells[i].Text;
        }
    }

    gvColumnsAsRows.DataSource = FlipDataTable(dt);
    gvColumnsAsRows.DataBind();
    gvColumnsAsRows.HeaderRow.Visible = false;
}
```

To flip rows into columns and vice versa:

```
public static System.Data.DataTable FlipDataTable(System.Data.DataTable dt)
{
    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    //Get all the rows and change into columns
    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
    }
    DataRow dr;
    //get all the columns and make it as rows
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        dr = table.NewRow();
        dr[0] = dt.Columns[j].ToString();
        for (int k = 1; k <= dt.Rows.Count; k++)
            dr[k] = dt.Rows[k - 1][j];
        table.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    return table;
}
```

I am getting the above mentioned error in **btnConvert_Data()** on line **dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);**. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

My final Output when I flip the Gridview should look like this:

[image: Flipped Gridview]

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

column header text and column name are different, which column name must be unique in a DataTable.

so for you instance, you can specify a different random name to the columns which have no column header text

and also, you need to detect if the Header is real string.Empty or something just looks like empty, in your case, the header text is never an empty value, it's `&nbsp;`

so your logic will never hit, i mean `cell.Text==""` will always returns false

so here is the solution

```
foreach (TableCell cell in GridView6.HeaderRow.Cells)
{
    if (cell.Text == "&nbsp;")
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()); //just some random value, i use guid, you can use anything you like to keep it unique.
    }
    else
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(cell.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: But i don't want any value. No random value as well. It should be empty.

Comment: that's not possible for column name. it must be unique. but you don't need to display it, you can separately set the column header text in DataGrid control

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that every column has a unique name. You can do that by checking if the column name exists and if so make it a unique one by adding the index to the column name.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
{
    string cellText = GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;

    //check if the column name exists and if so make it unique
    if (dt.Columns.Contains(cellText))
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(cellText + "_" + i);
    }
    else
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(cellText);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is showing &nbsp; in which I don't need. Any other option?

Comment: There is no `&nbsp;` in my snippet. But one way or another you have to make the colum names unique.

Comment: When I export this data to Excel It gives &nbsp;

Comment: Then remove it before adding it to the column.